# Asterisk. PHP. How to get phone number if I know SIP?

Tags: php, asterisk

We have asterisk server and GSM gateway. I need to know phone numbers that calls to asterisk in the current time. Now I can get SIP with command `core show channels` but I don't know how to get phone numbers.
I use phpAGI library:

```
$agi_manager = new AGI_AsteriskManager(null, $agi_config);
$connect = $agi_manager->connect();
$result = $agi_manager->command('core show channels');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of the 'core show channels' output is the channel ID. use it to issue the command `core show channel <id>` (no 's' at the end of channel!) to see more info about the channel, including the number of the calling party.

```
foreach(explode("\n", $result) as $line) {
   $cols = explode(" ", $line);
   $result2 = $agi_manager->command('core show channel '.$col[0]);
   if(preg_match('/Connected Line ID:\s*(\d+)/', $result2, $matches) {
      printf("Phone number: %s\n", $matches[1]);
   }
   else {
      printf("No phone number found for SIP Channel ID %s\n", $col[0]);
   }
}
```

Tested with Asterisk 1.8, your version may give different results. Just check a sample output of `core show channel`.